# Unity3d High level literature

Tags: unity

Is there any high level literature for mid professional programmers for Unity?
There are a lot of tutorials for beginners, but I can't find anything about main API, pipeline or engine architecture. Recommend, please!

Comment: **The Unity website** has all sorts of API documentation, a leisurely read-through of the resources there should be more than enough.  On top of that there are blogs, forums and sample projects to learn from.  What more are you looking for?

Comment: I know that there are a lot of blogs and samples, and absolute most of them are for beginners. I mean some professional opinion on this engine, some detailed analysis of unobvious aspects of usage in real projects. It's really hard to find.

something like this article btw:
http://blog.csdn.net/jixuguo/article/details/7351307

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been collecting some resources and hope to one day write up something sensible on the architecture but for now I can dump some of my links:

Nurturing Large Projects
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q9aeNtKKXeo

Pretty good introduction to creating and maintaining a larger project in Unity. They definitely take some shortcuts and overuse Singletons etc. but it's good for getting a base level of knowledge. They also provide the slides and a good list of further reading.

50 Tips for Working with Unity (Best Practices) 
http://devmag.org.za/2012/07/12/50-tips-for-working-with-unity-best-practices/

Continuing... When you're dealing with Unity, the underlying architecture for most of the things you're doing is component-based programming. You create GameObjects that have their behavior separated into discrete components like Collider, Rigidbody, Transform. There are some good books and blog posts about that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901251/component-based-game-engine-design http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy

Pretty much all of these are great practices that will help you figure out how to work out some practical parts of the architecture by yourself.